# how to make a buttons group responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So far my HTML and CSS. The button should be inline and also to have different   colors.  I have use also media queries but didn't work.

```css
.btn-defoult{
  width:450px; 
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #d9d9d9;

}
.btn-defoult1{
  width:450px; 
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #e3e1e1;

}
.btn-defoult2{
  width:450px;
  height: 50px; 
  background-color: #e9e9e9;

}
```

```html
 <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-defoult btn-responsive">Get here</button>
          <button class="btn btn-defoult1 btn-responsive">News</button>
          <button class="btn btn-defoult2 btn-responsive">Downloads</button> 
        </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: give your buttons {max-width: 450px;  width: 100%;}

Answer (score 2):

Use something along the lines of this code, perhaps tweak the values a bit, but this is your answer, your problem is that it stops being responsive from 500px and down right?

Below code is to give you an idea of what it would be, it's not tested

```
@media screen and (min-width: 100px) and (max-width:  540px) {
.btn-group {
width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the official Bootstrap's website:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Get here</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">News</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Download</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i changed your css a bit, if the window is smaller than the (width) 450px the buttons will be (max-width) 100% of the width

```css
.btn-group button {
  width: 100%; 
  max-width: 450px;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
}
.btn-defoult{
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
}
.btn-defoult1{
  background-color: #e3e1e1;
}
.btn-defoult2{
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
```

```html
 <div class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-defoult btn-responsive">Get here</button>
          <button class="btn btn-defoult1 btn-responsive">News</button>
          <button class="btn btn-defoult2 btn-responsive">Downloads</button> 
</div>
```